# A question about estimating non-filtered data

Tags: filter

We have made data acquisition with 200Hz sampling rate which sampled amplifier analog signals. But unfortunately the amplifier filter was set to 20Hz and it shouldn't have been using the filter. 20Hz active 3rd order bessel filter was used.

Is there a way to recover this data as if it werent filtered?

Comment: Probably not, as your desired data is now likely buried in the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could apply an inverse filter, but with a third order roll off having been applied half a decade below where you wanted it you will be looking at 30dB of gain by the time you get to the sampling limit at 100Hz, which will bring the noise up by 30dB....

I doubt you are going to get anything useful past maybe 50Hz or so, and it seems like a lot of faffing about if you can just re run the measurement.

It very much depends on what the data set is, and how important the 'high frequency' content is.

Time to take that amplifier and do some frequency sweeps and FFTs to get the gain and phase response of that filter (And you really want it to be that particular unit), then fire up matlab and start playing.

Comment: I can apply signals at constant amplitudes with a freq range between 0 and 200Hz or more with a function generator and see the responses at a scope- But how can I conver these what I se on the scope to an inverse filter/function?

Comment: You need to know the phase as well as the amplitude, best way to make the measurements is probably with a PC sound card and some audio analysis software, then take the resulting data into your favourite math tool (Matlab, Octave, Scilab, whatever works for you) and do the sums.

Comment: You mean sweeping the input with a function generator and sampling the output at lets say at 30kHz? What will I do with the samples I obtain?

Comment: That's an ill-posed problem, isn't it?

Comment: If you use a function generator you will need to sample both the amplifiers input and output so that you have a phase reference for doing the sums. Basically what you want is a network analyser stle I/Q data set for the filter you are trying to reverse out as a file you can then manipulate. Complex I/Q data is what you are really after as you can then compute an inverse transform, and from there it is all over bar the FFT. The trap is that applying 30dB of gain (which is what you will need at high frequency) is going to raise the noise floor rather a lot.